# python: list index of out of range

Tags: python, csv

```
  for row in c:
    c1.append(row[0:13])

  for row in c1:
    row.append(float(row[13])/100)
    row.append(float(row[12])/float(row[13])/100)
    row.append(math.log10(float(row[12])))
```

`c` contains a csv file with many rows and columns
`c1` is a subset of `c` containing only the first 14 elements

i am getting `IndexError: list index out of range` on `row.append(float(row[13])/100)`

does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: How many elements are in `row`? I'm assuming less then 14, which is your problem (Your trying to append item 14 (`[13]`) which doesn't exist.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392677/python-list-assignment-index-out-of-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows in c1 don't actually contain 14 elements, they contain 13.

The second index in a slice is non-inclusive.  When you append `row[0:13]` to `c1` you are appending from element 0 to the element *before* 13.  Hence, there are only 13 elements.

This is why you get `IndexError: list index out of range` on `row.append(float(row[13])/100)`.  `row[13]` is an attempt to access a non-existent 14th element.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if there are less than 13 elements in the initial array, `c1.append(row[0:13])` won't throw an error either.